# Find general solution of the given trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry

> Find general solution of the given trigonometric equation:
>
> $\sin^24x + \cos^2x = 2 \sin4x \cos^2x$

I tried converting the whole equation in the form of $2x$ and got a pretty complicated equation involving $\sin2x, \cos2x, \sin^22x$ and $\cos^22x$. I have got no idea how to further solve that equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x$ be a solution of the given equation. Associate the equation of degree two in $T$,
$$
\tag{$*$}
T^2 -2T\cos^2 x+\cos^2 x=0\ .
$$
It has the solution $T_1=\sin 4x$, so the equation $(*)$ has discriminant $\ge 0$ (w.r.t. $T$), we obtain then $\cos^4 x-\cos^2 x\ge 0$. This is equivalent to $-\sin^2 x\cos^2x\ge 0$. So either $\sin x$ or $\cos x$ vanishes.

- The case $\sin x=0$: We obtain $\sin 4x=0$ and $\cos x=\pm 1$, no solutions.
- The case $\cos x=0$: We obtain also $\sin 4x=2\sin 2x\cos 2x=4\sin x\cos x\cos 2x= 0$. This case always delivers solutions. So $x$ is an odd multiple of $\pi/2$.

---

*Later edit:* After the comment, here is an alternative way to finish by remaining inside trigonometry:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\sin^2 4x + \cos^2x - 2 \sin4x \cos^2x
\\
&\qquad=
4\sin^2 2x\cos^22x + \cos^2x - 4 \sin2x\cos 2x \cos^2x
\\
&\qquad=
16\sin^2 x\cos^2 x\cos^22x + \cos^2x - 8 \sin x\cos x\cos 2x \cos^2x
\\
&\qquad=
\cos^2 x\Big(\ 
16\sin^2 x\cos^22x  - 8 \sin x\cos x\cos 2x + 1
\ \Big)
\\
&\qquad=
\cos^2 x\Big(\ 
16\sin^2 x\cos^22x  - 8 \sin x\cos x\cos 2x + \cos^2x\ +\sin^2x
\ \Big)
\\
&\qquad=
\cos^2 x
\underbrace
{\Big(\ 
(4\sin x\cos 2x  - \cos x)^2 +\sin^2x
\ \Big)}_{\ge 0}
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
The first / last expression in the chain is zero, iff

- either $\cos x=0$,
- or the parenthesis above vanishes, for this, we need in particular $\sin x =0$, which implies $\sin 4x=0$ and $\cos x=\pm 1$, so we never get a solution.

(This is in essence the same solution...)

Comment: Thanks. That is a great approach to the question. But can this be solved using just trigonometric identities as I am dealing with a chapter on trigonometric equations and identities?

Answer (score 3):

Rearrange the equation as follows,

$$\sin^24x + \cos^2x - 2 \sin4x \cos^2x$$
$$=(\cos^2x - \sin 4x)^2 -\cos^4 x+\cos^2x$$
$$=(\cos^2x - \sin 4x)^2 +\cos^2x \sin^2x$$
$$=(\cos^2x - 2\sin 2x\cos2x)^2 +\frac14\sin^2 2x=0$$

where both terms vanish, leading to the following system of equations,
$$\sin2x =0$$
$$\cos^2x=2\cos2x\sin2x=0$$

Thus, the valid solutions are $x=\frac\pi2+n\pi$.

Comment: $(\cos^2x - \sin 4x)^2 -\cos^4 x+\cos^2x$ How did you get this?

Comment: @Aditya Jain - Note $(\cos^2x - \sin 4x)^2 = \cos^4x -2\sin4x\cos^2+\sin^24x$. Then the term $\cos^4x$ cancels.

Answer (score 0):

$\sin^24x + \cos^2x = 2 \sin4x \cos^2x$

$\sin^24x-2 \sin4x \cos^2x + \cos^2x = 0$

$\sin^24x-2 \sin4x \cos^2x +\cos^4x-\cos^4x+ \cos^2x = 0$

$(\sin4x-\cos^2x)^2 +\cos^2x(1-\cos^2x)  = 0$

$(\sin4x-\cos^2x)^2 \geqslant 0$

$\cos^2x(1-\cos^2x) \geqslant 0$

$\Rightarrow \sin4x-\cos^2x=\cos^2x(1-\cos^2x)  = 0$

$\ cos^2x = 1 \Rightarrow\sin4x \neq  1 \; \varnothing$

$\ cosx = 0 \Rightarrow\sin4x= 0 \;OK$

$ x =\frac {\pi}{2}+\pi*n\in \ {Z}  $